# How do you stop McAfee from quarantining your .EXE?

Tags: anti-virus, c, visual-studio-2019

I have a history with McAfee quarantining my C code in Microsoft Visual Studio and [others](https://community.mcafee.com/t5/LiveSafe/My-exe-files-are-being-quarantined/td-p/664736) have had the same problem.

[There are solutions](https://community.mcafee.com/t5/Malware/How-to-stop-McAfee-from-Quarauntining-something-it-THINKS-is-a/td-p/528235#:%7E:text=If%20you%20Open%20your%20McAfee,the%20application%20now%20works%20fine.), but that requires every .EXE in all your solutions to be whitelisted manually.
I would prefer that I didn't have to do that, but it seems that's the only way.

I followed the instruction to exclude the file and went back to coding. After I rebuilt my project McAfee alerted me that it removed it from the exclusion list because the file changed. So, either I shut off the live scan every time I want to practice coding, or I just don't code.
I know some of you out there must have a good solution so do you guys know if there a better solution?

I called their helpline and they told me to whitelist the EXE (devenv.exe) for Microsoft Visual Studio and it seemed to work but then later it stopped my project from running entirely considering it a virus threat.

Comment: I called them again and they want to remote access my computer? Yeah, buddy, not happening,

Comment: I've had the same issue - just disable live scanning while programming, and enable it again after you're done, just don't download any suspicious programs during that time :)

Comment: @CarsonFujita-Turnbull - McAfee **never** ask you for remote access to your computer.  You most definitely did NOT call McAfee.

Comment: Do you have a choice of other antimalware, or are you in a corporate environment where McAfee is mandated?

Comment: No, no @Ramhound I am certain I called them. I called 1-800-937-2237. Which is listed on https://www.mcafee.com/enterprise/en-us/forms/website-feedback.html

Comment: @DrMoishe I am just a kid who wants to practice his c, but I am not 
eligible for a refund due to their refund policy and I can't afford any other service. Plus my computer, Asus ZenBook 15 prefers McAfee for some reason.

Comment: @CarsonFujita-Turnbull - What do you mean it "prefers" McAfee.  Have you tried just uninstalling it and using the McAfee tool to completely uninstall McAfee products?  Any event, the only solution to your problem, is to exclude your project folder.  Of course it's probably important to determine what about your code is being flagged by the McAfee behavioral scanner.

Comment: @Ramhound . Well, it seems ASUS has a partnership with MacAfee that's what I mean. Sadly they apparently removed the feature to exclude the project folder. They want me to send the data of all my projects so their service can exclude it but that makes no sense because why do I have to email them EVERY time I want to code?

Comment: @CarsonFujita-Turnbull - I find it hard to believe you cannot exclude a folder in McAfee.  If you indicate what you have installed I can do some research.